# RViz Motion Planning Error: Failed to load motion planning plugin library

Tags: rviz, moveit, ubuntu, motionplanning, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was running a Moveit tutorial on Motion Planning (ROS Indigo version) when I got the error,

```
MotionPlanning
The class required for this display, 'moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning', could not be loaded.
Error:
Failed to load library /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libmoveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

The first time when I launched the tutorial, I got a similar error and fixed it by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

as suggested in [Rviz motion_planning Error: Failed to load library](http://answers.ros.org/question/194341/rviz-motion_planning-error-failed-to-load-library/), *but has not worked since*.

I have installed opencv3.2.0, is that the reason why this isn't working? Or is the opencv plugin a part of ROS?
I checked the library files in Moveit and this is the output:-

```
>> ls /opt/ros/indigo/lib | grep open
libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so
libopenni2_camera_nodelet.so
libopenni2_driver_lib.so
libopenni2_wrapper.so
openni2_camera

>> ls /opt/ros/indigo/lib | grep motion
libmoveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.so
libmoveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.so.0.7.3
libmoveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin.so
libmoveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin.so.0.7.3
libstdr_ideal_motion_controller.so
libstdr_omni_motion_controller.so

>> ls /usr/local/lib | grep libopencv_imgproc.so
libopencv_imgproc.so
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0
```

Is there a way to make RViz use the 3.2 version instead?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263585/rviz-motion-planning-error:-failed-to-load-motion-planning-plugin-library/) by [anonymous28838](https://answers.ros.org/users/28838/anonymous28838/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the plugin is compiled against packages that use OpenCV 2.4, and can't be used with a different version. You may be able to recompile the moveit rviz plugin with the updated version of OpenCV

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0